# Distance between istream_iterators

Tags: c++, distance, istream-iterator

I am trying to count the amount of elements read by `std::cin` by using `std::distance` for the constructor argument of a vector in advance, like so:

```cpp
// Gives correct amount, but now can't use to put into vector
int size = std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

std::vector v(size);

// Already read from stream
std::copy(...);
```

Obviously I can complete this in one step with `std::copy`, but that would require setting a size beforehand. My question isn't about vectors though, it's about getting the size of an arbitrary input using `std::istream_iterator` without affecting the stream. Any ideas?

Comment: *"Obviously I can complete this in one step with std::copy, but that would require setting a size beforehand"* Yes and no, respectively. Do you know about `back_insert_iterator`?

Comment: Even if I agree with Pretorian answer, this is a very strange behavior to have size == 0. As stated in that [document](http://www.oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/STL/Volume/prw421.htm), For input iterators r and s, r==s does not imply ++r == ++s:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) is an [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), which means it only supports a single pass over the range you're iterating. There's no way to figure out the size, and then go back to the beginning to read the data.

You can read from `std::cin` (or any other input stream) using `std::copy` without knowing the size beforehand, just use [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to append the data being read to the `vector`.

```
std::vector v;
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), 
           std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
           std::back_inserter(v) );
```

Comment: Well, with seekable streams you could `seekg` to 0 and iterate again. I'm not saying it's a good idea...

Comment: @jrok Yes, of course. What I meant was there's no way to make the same iterator *walk backwards*.